# How to calculate the size of the statically allocated string in the calling function in C?

Tags: c, string, function, size, sizeof

How to get the value `200` in the function check_size?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int check_size(char *ptr)
{
    //if (sizeof(ptr) == 200)
    //{
    //   ...
    //}
    printf("%ld \n", sizeof(ptr));
    printf("%ld \n", sizeof(*ptr));
    printf("%ld \n", strlen(ptr));

    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    char ptr[200]="\0";

    int s = check_size(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without using a smart pointer.

Comment: In this code, ptr is not a dynamically allocated memory. Tough not sure 100%, the program execution will even fail to start if the operating system fails to allocate 200 bytes of memory. So, talking about a consistent operating system, you can be sure you've got 200 bytes of memory allocated, once you get the process up & running.

Comment: The correct format specifier for `size_t`, which is what both `sizeof()` and `strlen()` return, is `%zu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the value `200` in the function `check_size`? How to calculate the size of the statically allocated string in the calling function in C?

Since the size of `ptr` is known at compile-time and you also should hardcode integer literals as less as possible inside any source code, just use a macro constant to hold the amount of elements. With that you can easily calculate the size of the array in the function `check_size()`:

[Example program](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAKylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgATAAZSAB1TTCS2pp19I09vXzoLK1tdByc3GTlMBT8GAmZiAgC9A2NZeUU6FLSCCJt7Rxd3aVT0zKCc6uLLUujytwBKGVRtYmQOAHIAUmcAZktkHSwAagHh9Sr8VAA6BBnsAdcAQSHR2nHtKZm5gmJLYGXV9a3N7awqJsn2UQIESbdXS8vLAknkBESAazEPgAXpgIL80pMAFQeY5tD4AdgAQpdJmjJh4TvQqBAhs4hoZgdppoZ1LQ8aRJiDMKgcTC4fDhkj0SyWQB6NlUvCgya06YANlcEOIA0FqPRmK%2BOLxBKJJLJFK5oNpEHpxDa0IeqmAz0ZzMmHKVmF5VEmz2NaWIzAAnotxWjJdjcc58c5CcSBqTyS7KdSVbD1XrWcGDZzqSazX8Magvo4zagBUKEGlRa47ZsWY6CNKXbKPV7FVViI8IAG2kGQ%2BzOY8dS8%2BeaqcdTumrhsWcRMARurRJpwZijrgiACIfTZfSa6ZiWCDwwcDtvo4UY46epE156eofTYZbvF/VisVAypmjhdo34AoHcsFl/v2yYdrvEHvvE%2BDod9DqsEB9Qx9UgGH0rj/qgP7qFSXQ9Ma2ycP%2BBA/sB5akP8IDDMMixoZhWHYfyQg/tw/6AcBpCgX0/7SCA7jwUBn6kHAsAwIgKCoLoHh4OwZAUOCLFsRxKDAAAnM4pB3KwBCOBREB2Ah/52JYaTWj%2BsGkGgui6KoBAAPK0Kwik0aQWCTqI7AyQZeAdkkABumAUfpmAAB6JNo4mmbG376aweB2FaxDWpoWBKXBJy6IFHQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCAEhiFInl2BRkAdKgsJ%2BLZAC0ADqbCsJMBWOMQJDkQkSTKBApi1AYnAmGoJRRDEgheD4%2BT%2BFoWTtaEXUtWUTiNbkiRdYUNQ9UEI1VeNDSDS0w0yA09WCFURQLW1nAdNIkG9FwX4/n%2BAGmaR9kABz8rl/LcJMwDIMgkwCYsziTBAuCECQ0wjI1kyaKx7FxjBGrqHBMlIShhjuO5BGkCFUMnfppHkZRpDUYhdGMRASBdAQHjOeQlCqbx5SNZg%2BBEEt4WMCwJkxQA7laHihXhv6EadP4wZM9OEC8F1XTdd0PU9L1gzRSF/MwWBODOyFcK40P4f%2B8PuERIE/ijVHgx0KFoRh2EG2huHucM7NIxraPg5j8D0UxxOA5xRM8Q7KDjCIgkKyJ7HicQknSfpcm0ApgUqSx6n0NpummYZ7smfp%2BAWYo1m2cRDlOS5%2BluaZqU%2BX5GD9MpTYhX0sFhXQNNRVwvACMJ8XiJIQheelstZV1tmVXkfgqGoq1k81TStaTISdX4vfD2EtCbUPo3VbQE0ZFNDXxJ3BTzQPQ1rSti%2Bbxt6%2BLQdnTdPt22s8daskT%2B/PXbdbuiCLaauG9H2U99wy/f9JPEK/zgg2LiE66hdChtDas1hirRGxFkYyFRujWittsYgFxvjAghNuIAz4sJcmn0qbl0inTXgjNmDMxLrRdyZ8OaDBGK9HmzxJhX0FrfYA99FjEVgRLTAUtyiyxhsrIwqsKGa0tuLABetgEG1ZqbCB6syJCP/qzZwZtIEWzYR0ayvsu7cCAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define length 200                            // macro constant `length`.

int check_size(char *ptr)
{
    printf("%zu \n", sizeof(*ptr));           // size of `char`
    printf("%zu \n", sizeof(*ptr) * length);  // size of the array.
    printf("%zu \n", sizeof(ptr));            // size of the pointer to `char`.
    printf("%zu \n", strlen(ptr));            // length of the string.

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char ptr[length] = "\0";                  // macros can be used here.

    check_size(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 
200 
8 
0
```

Comment: This seems to be a feasible solution for me. By using a global length definition common to the called and calling functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When an array is used as function argument, it is converted to a pointer to its first element.  As a result, a function cannot get the size of an array passed as a parameter.

Regarding your attempts:

```
printf("%ld \n", sizeof(ptr));
```

As `ptr` is a `char *` this will give you the size of that pointer (typically 8).

```
printf("%ld \n", sizeof(*ptr));
```

This will give you the size of what `ptr` points to, specifically a `char` which is defined to be 1.

```
printf("%ld \n", strlen(ptr));
```

Assuming `ptr` points to a null terminated string, this will give you the length of the string.

The array size needs to be passed in as a separate parameter for the function to know it.  The expression `sizeof(ptr)` *if used in `main`* will give you the size of the array in bytes.

Comment: Yes I get 0 for the last print statement. So what do I pass as argument to the check_size function in order to check the size of the passed char array is allocated for 200?

Comment: @Sethuraman That's the problem, you can't. You can only use `sizeof` on the array in the scope where it was defined.  So any function that needs to know the size of an array has to have it passed explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand now that it's a shortcoming of C.

Answer (score 0):

Something to clarify: There is no concept of "array size" to the called function. All it is given is a pointer to one byte.

Now, if you were to give the array a particular initialization, like a 199 character length string, you could do it with `strlen()`. Or you could pass in the array size, although that's trivial.

Overall though, there is no way to do exactly what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the value 200 in the function check_size?

Rather that have a function accepting a `char*`, have function that accepts a pointer to array 200 of char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_size(char (*ptr)[200]) {
  printf("%zu \n", sizeof(ptr));
  printf("%zu \n", sizeof(*ptr));
  printf("%zu \n", strlen(*ptr));
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  char ptr[200] = "\0";
  check_size(&ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
8 
200 
0
```

---

GTG